# Insert element into elements?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

How can I add a link to a footer with Simple HTML DOM and normal PHP? I use this to find the footer:

```
$html = file_get_html('/index.php'); 
// Find footer
foreach($html->find('footer') as $f){
    //the normal php code here
}
```

Now how can I use PHP to add the link into the footer?

Otherwise if you can do it without Simple HTML DOM, how do you?
I would rather use normal PHP than Simple HTML DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// create a dom
$dom = new DOMDocument();
// load the html url
$dom->loadHtmlFile('http://localhost/index.php');

// get the #footer element
$footer = $dom->getElementById('footer');
if ($footer) {
  // create a link element
  $link = $dom->createElement('a');
  // set the href attribute
  $link->setAttribute('href', '...');
  // add some text content to the link
  $link->appendChild($dom->createTextNode('...'));
  // append the link into the footer
  $footer->appendChild($link);
}

echo $dom->saveHtml();
```